# A strange number appears to me in FragmentPagerAdapter when I call a translation R.string

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

I'm trying to put a text translation into a FragmentPagerAdapter
With all attempts and use
return (R.string.Chats) + "";

A strange number appeared to me in three tab ,

photo : https://i.stack.imgur.com/znIB2.png

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context context;

public SectionPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@NonNull

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position==0){
        ChatsFragment chatsFragment =new ChatsFragment();
        return chatsFragment;
    }
    else if(position==1){
        FriendsFragment firendsFragment =new FriendsFragment();
        return firendsFragment;
    }
    else if(position==2){
        RequestsFragment requestsFragment =new RequestsFragment();
        return requestsFragment;
    }
    else return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){


    if(position==0){

        return  (R.string.Chats) + "";

    }
    else if(position==1){
        return  (R.string.Friends) + "";
    }
    else if(position==2){
        return  (R.string.Requests) + "";
    }
    else return null;
}
```

}

The problem in particular here is that I want to, in short, add the text through R.string !

```
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){


    if(position==0){

        return  (R.string.Chats) + "";

    }
    else if(position==1){
        return  (R.string.Friends) + "";
    }
    else if(position==2){
        return  (R.string.Requests) + "";
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#String). You need to extract the string value. Right now, you're just printing the resource id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.string.something return the String resource id that string have. You can pass the context to constructor of view and initialize the property context that you have in your adapter class.

Then you can get strings like this:

```
context.getString(R.string.something)
```

Comment: Thank you @Emanuel for the reply When using return context.getString(R.string.Chats); I get an error Cannot resolve symbol 'context ' 
I use private Context context; When you run the app, it closes suddenly  why ?

Comment: Because you are not initializing the context. As I request the context as param in yout adapter class like this:

` 
public SectionPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
   this.context = context;
}

 ` 

And then you can use the context in your adapter without error.

Comment: @Roanda When you create the adapter you send the fragmentManager and context bu using

` this ` keyword

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.Chats` - it's not a `String` it's resource identifier(has an integer type). If you want to get String from resources you should use:
`context.getString(R.string.Chats)` instead of `R.string.Chats`. The same for another page titles.
just re-write you `getPageTitle` method and it will be ok

Comment: Thank you @Anatolii Chub very much for the help and clarification of the problem
When using return context.getString(R.string.Chats); 
I get an error Cannot resolve symbol 'context '
I use     private Context context;
When you run the app, it closes suddenly